# Adding columns in table

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have display quantity and price attributes on my table from database but for some reasons I don't save the total into database but I display total by multiplying `quantity * total` on the table when data is being fetched.

Total for every column on my table is being displayed accurately. Is there a way that I can add all total columns on the table in my html?

PS: with my code, it only displays the total of the current column of the table

**Table**

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($items as $items)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$item>id }}</td>
            <td>{{$item->quantity}}</td> 
            <td>{{ $item->price}}</td>
            <td>{{ $item->quantity * $item->price}}</td>
        </tr>    
    @endforeach
    <p>Sum: {{ $item->quantity * $item->price}}</p>
</tbody>
```

Comment: you can easily google this kind of things do not post this kind of questions here. you can use JS as well https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/jnwrc5ay/347/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<tbody>
    {{ $total = 0 }}
    @foreach($items as $items)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$item>id }}</td>
            <td>{{$item->quantity}}</td> 
            <td>{{ $item->price}}</td>
            <td>{{ $item->quantity * $item->price}}</td>
            {{ $total = $total + ($item->quantity * $item->price) }}
        </tr>

    @endforeach
    <p>Sum: {{ $total }}</p>
</tbody>
```

Comment: don't do copy paste you copied sapnesh ans. and just lil bit modified it.

Comment: Yeah dude, look at the time difference, < 1min, also his code doesn't work.

Comment: yup ! you are correct let me give you +1 for this :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [blade's](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade) `@php` directive like this

```
<tbody>
@php
$total = 0
    @foreach($items as $items)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$item>id }}</td>
        <td>{{$item->quantity}}</td> 
        <td>{{$item->price}}</td>
        <td>{{$total = $total + ($item->quantity * $item->price)}}</td>        
    </tr>        
    @endforeach

    <p>Sum: {{ $total }}</p>
@endphp
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try the following:**

```
{{ $sum = 0 }}
<tbody>
    @foreach($items as $items)
       <tr>
          <td>{{$item>id }}</td>
          <td>{{$item->quantity}}</td> 
          <td>{{ $item->price}}</td>
          <td>{{ $item->quantity * $item->price}}</td>
      </tr>
      $sum+ = $item->quantity * $item->price;
    @endforeach
    <p>Sum: {{ $sum }}</p>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume here `$items` is a `Illuminate\Support\Collection`.  You can calculate a sum using a closure:

```
$items->sum( function ($item) {
    return $item->quantity * $item->price;
});
```

Or in your blade template:

```
{{ $items->sum( function ($item) {
    return $item->quantity * $item->price;
}); }}
```

See [Laravel Collections docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-sum).